# How could i set max age in Lua

Tags: lua

An example is `if age >= 18 then` but if i want the max age to be for example 30? How could i make that happen? I tried `elseif age >= 30 then` but when i run the script it wont work. So how could i make max age. Do you guys have any idea how i could make this possible? I started lua for one month ago. I'm not that good at lua. 
Here is an example: age = 30

```
if age >= 18 then
   print("You can enter")
elseif age >= 30 then
   print("Your " age " is so you are to old!")
else
   print("You cannot enter!")
end
io.read()
```

Comment: Although you use Lua, this is a general programming question and not directly related to Lua.

Answer (score 2):

When using `if age >= 18` as the first condition, then you will never pass to the subsequent `else` statements if the age is >= 18, because the condition is already consumed at the first branch, which also includes the age range of >=30

In general, in `if` condition statement, only one branch will be executed for single examination.

So, you need to add narrower conditions first, then get it wider gradually in next else branches; and then remove the `else` at the end as it will match any other age, and this is not what you want as you need 30 as a max age.

So you can solve this by flipping both the first and second conditions:

```
if age >= 30 then 
   io.write("Your ", age, " is so you are to old!")
elseif age >= 18 then
   print("You can enter")
elseif age <18 and age >0 then
   print("You cannot enter!")
end
io.read()
```

Comment: There is also a error in the concatenation the OP had in their `age >= 30` print string.`"Your " age " is so you are to old!"` should be `"Your " .. age .. " is so you are to old!"`

Comment: @Nifim sorry I didn't notice it, you can use `string.format` method for printing non-string values, please check updated code

Comment: making it 3 args will make it print with tabs around the age. That might look weird, but it does correct the syntax error

Comment: @Nifim thank you very much, I am not that `lua` expert, I just `print` for debugging purpose; is there a way of getting rid of those tabs?

Comment: @Nifim I googled it, it should be `io.write` and updated answer though .. thanks again!